# Numpy Attribute error pymc

Tags: python, numpy, pymc

I'm trying to implement a state-space model using pymc and numpy.

As such I'm using numpy arrays with dtype object to avoid a setting an array element with a sequence error. As demonstrated [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aflaxman/8654408)

I then use a list as a 'container' of pymc nodes suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458972/pymc-how-can-i-describe-a-state-space-model) and implemented [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/wiki/Surplus)

My issue comes when I try to use numpy's exponential function which won't work on an array with a dtype of object.

When I try to change the dtype to float I get the setting an array with a sequence error.

Here's some code which replicates the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import pylab

df = pd.read_csv('http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/E0.csv')

results = df[['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG']]

teams = sorted(results['HomeTeam'].unique())

y1 = np.array(results['FTHG'])

y2 = np.array(results['FTAG'])

home_team = pd.Series(np.arange(20),index=teams)[results['HomeTeam']].values

away_team = pd.Series(np.arange(20),index=teams)[results['AwayTeam']].values

game = range(df.shape[0])

nteams = len(teams)
ngames = len(game)



df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%y'))

df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: (x - df.Date.ix[0]).days//7)


week = pd.factorize(df.Date)[0]

nweeks = max(week)+1

nweeks

home = pm.Normal('home', 0, .0001, value=[0]*nteams,size=(nteams,))
away = pm.Normal('away', 0, .0001, value=0)
mu_att = pm.Normal('mu_att', 0, .0001)
mu_def = pm.Normal('mu_def', 0, .0001, value=0)
tau_att = pm.Gamma('tau_att', .1, .1)
tau_def = pm.Gamma('tau_def', .1, .1)
sigma = pm.Gamma('sigma', .1, .1)


atts_0 = pm.Normal("atts_0",
               mu=mu_att,
               tau=tau_att,
               size=(nteams,1))

defs_0 = pm.Normal("atts_0",
               mu=mu_def,
               tau=tau_def,
               size=(nteams,1))

atts = [atts_0]
defs = [defs_0]

for i in range(1,nweeks+1):
    a = pm.Normal('a_%i'%i, mu = atts[i-1],tau=sigma)
    attsi = pm.Lambda('atts_%i' % i, lambda a=a: np.eye(nteams).dot(a) - np.ones(nteams).dot(np.ones(nteams).T))
    atts.append(attsi)

for i in range(1,nweeks+1):
    d = pm.Normal('d_%i'%i, mu = defs[i-1],tau=sigma)
    defsi = pm.Lambda('defs_%i' % i, lambda d=d: np.eye(nteams).dot(d) - np.ones(nteams).dot(np.ones(nteams).T))
    defs.append(defsi)

atts = np.array(atts[1:])
defs = np.array(defs[1:])


@pm.deterministic
def home_theta(home=home,
           atts=atts,
           defs=defs,
           week=week,
           home_team=home_team,
           away_team=away_team): 
    return  np.exp((home[home_team] + atts[week][home_team] + defs[week][away_team]))    


LazyFunction.pyx in pymc.LazyFunction.LazyFunction.force_compute (pymc/LazyFunction.c:2409)()

<ipython-input-35-9977366624a3> in home_theta(home, atts, defs, week, home_team, away_team)
  6                home_team=home_team,
  7                away_team=away_team): 
----> 8     return  np.exp((home[home_team] + atts[week][home_team] + defs[week][away_team]))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error

```
----> 8     return  np.exp((home[home_team] + atts[week][home_team] + defs[week][away_team]))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

I'm guessing that the `numpy` module (named `np`) has been replaced with an array, a `np.ndarray` object.  In other words, something is doing something like:

```
np = np.array(...) # or
np = x + 3  # where x=np.array...
```

Possibly it's the `@pm.deterministic` decorator.

Without knowing anything about `pymc` you could try using `numpy` as the import name instead of `np`.  In other words, try to bypass this renaming.

```
import numpy
....
numpy.exp(...)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but this still produces the same error





`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp' `